# while playing videos and jump some location in video it takes some more time to jump that location?

Tags: 12.04

1. I have dell insprion n5010 500 gb hd,4gb ram 1gb intell HD graphics i installed ubuntu 12.10 i'm a new person to linux while playing videos the player keep on struggling also the system start up time is too slow. help to improve it
2. I have dell insprion in that there is option to disable the battery charging in windows but in linux not how to enable this option

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your video drivers aren't installed. Go to your ADDITIONAL DRIVERS option in your system or preferences menu. If it's a 12.10 it will be in SOFTWARE SOURCE as JOCKEY-GTK seems to have been incorporated into SOFTWARE SOURCES. Choose the appropriate driver to activate harware acceleration to eliminate all the video jumping and skipping and what have you.